# Transition a linear animation on hover off

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm trying to spin an SVG logo infinitely on hover like a vinyl on a record player and then slow down/ease out the animation when hovering off, like removing a needle from the player.

However, I can't work out how to make the smooth transition on hover off. Any ideas?

```
    @-webkit-keyframes spin { 
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
}
@keyframes spin { 
  100% {  
  transform:rotate(360deg); 
  } 
}

transition: all 1s ease;

&:hover {
 -webkit-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 1s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `:not(:hover)` *pseudo-class* pair, which fires the `animation` after the *element* is *"unhovered"*, together with a *wrapper element* whose `animation` in the opposite direction (`-`) nullifies the one of the *child* on page load.

To avoid any visual deviations and inconsistencies the *animation-timing-function* of `linear` is used and recommended:

```css
.vinyl {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: repeating-radial-gradient(#fff, #fff 1px, #000 1px, #000 2px);
}

.vinyl:hover {
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin { 
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

.vinyl:not(:hover) {
  animation: stop 2s ease-out;
}

@keyframes stop {
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

span {
  display: inline-block; /* required */
  animation: nullify 2s ease-out;
  background: #ddd; /* just for demo */
}

@keyframes nullify {
  100% {transform: rotate(-360deg)}
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div class="vinyl"></div>
</span>
```